# Set minimum order price for a shipping method

Tags: php, shipping, javascript, shipping-methods, html

I want to set a minimum order amount for a specific shipping method.
I want a specific shipping method to get enable when subtotal price of order reaches to the specific price which I had set before just like minimum order amount in payment methods.

i added this code to `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml` --> `<config><sections><carriers><groups><flatrate><fields>`:

```
<min_order_total translate="label">
        <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>157</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</min_order_total>
```

and i added this code to `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/config.xml`--> `<config><default><carriers><flatrate>`:

```
<min_order_total>0</min_order_total>
```

and added this code to `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`

```
$total = $this->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal();
$minTotal = $this->getConfigData('min_order_total');

if(!empty($minTotal) && ($total < $minTotal)) {
    return false;
}
```

now my `Flatrate.php` look like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Shipping
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Flat rate shipping model
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Shipping
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'flatrate';
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
     */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $total = $this->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal();
        $minTotal = $this->getConfigData('min_order_total');

        if(!empty($minTotal) && ($total < $minTotal)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('flatrate');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('flatrate'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }

}
```

but i get this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBaseGrandTotal() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php on line 51`.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the payment methods is done by this way - in each payment method in **etc/system.xml** there is this code:

```
                <min_order_total translate="label">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>98</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </min_order_total>
```

and then in **app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php -> protected function _canUseMethod($method)**:

```
/**
 * Checking for min/max order total for assigned payment method
 */
$total = $this->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal();
$minTotal = $method->getConfigData('min_order_total');
$maxTotal = $method->getConfigData('max_order_total');

if((!empty($minTotal) && ($total < $minTotal)) || (!empty($maxTotal) && ($total > $maxTotal))) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

So you can copy this in each shipping method. For an example for Flat Rate shipping method in **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml** -> `<flatrate>` -> `<fields>` add this:

```
                <min_order_total translate="label">
                    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>98</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </min_order_total>
```

and in **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php -> public function collectRates** add this:

```
$total = $request->getPackageValue();
$minTotal = $this->getConfigData('min_order_total');

if(!empty($minTotal) && ($total < $minTotal)) {
    return false;
}
```

If you like it for all shipping methods maybe you can think of altering some way **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php** (not each method one by one).

Comment: can you check my question again please?

Comment: You didn't put the code in the method body and also the method is abstract so you can't put a code in it (please see here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php). So please put the code in each shipping method that you like. When I wrote to think some way in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php, I didn't mean in the abstract public function collectRates, I only give you a direction/tip to look at this class.

Comment: it faces to an error. can you check it again please?

Comment: You modify <tablerate> then Freeshipping.php (there is no sense). Maybe you want to modify Tablerate.php because free shipping has already such field (Minimum Order Amount). Put the code at the beginning of collectRates function. And also there is no point of modifying config.xml because it's only for default value.

Comment: again this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBaseGrandTotal() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php on line 51

Comment: Sorry, try with `$request->getPackageValue()` instead of `$this->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal()`.